# Using the 3DS file export in 2.93 - how to export with textures?

Tags: texturing, export

Dear Blender community,

I do have a .blend file that includes textured models with UVs. The materials are set up like in the screenshot (texture into base color of principled BSDF):

[image]

After exporting using the new 3DS exporter from addons-contrib (https://github.com/blender/blender-addons-contrib). After exporting, the textures are gone. The UV maps get exported, but it is missing the textures. After re-importing using the same addon, the material looks like this:

[image]

It changed the name of the material accordin to the name of the texture, but the texture itself is gone. According to https://developer.blender.org/D7454 the addon now supports texturing, even PBR. Am I doing something wrong?

I have all the textures in the same folderas the .blend and I save the .3ds to exactly that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filenames are limited to 8 letters plus suffix, means the maximum characters is 12.
3ds only supports filenames in DOS 8.3 format

Comment: Wow. Welcome to 2021, Autodesk ! Other pros of using 3ds (from wikipedia) :     All meshes must be made of triangles.
    The number of vertices and polygons per mesh is limited to 65536.
    Accurate vertex normals cannot be stored in the .3ds file.
    Object, light and camera names are limited to 10 characters. Material names are limited to 16 characters.
    Directional light sources are not supported.

Comment: Sounds like Autodesk is taking downward compatibility very seriously... I mean sure, a lot of users swear on their 1990 first edition. Filenames limited to 8 characters... the 3ds files or the textures or everything?

Comment: Thank you, this is crazy o_O

Comment: The 3ds filename is not limited, only texture filenames. Directional light is possible if you use spotlight
It is also possible to create meshes with quads, but they will be converted to triangles during the export process

Answer (score 0):

On the exporter file, search for `[:12]` and replace it with `[:999]`
That should allow huge names on objects and textures to be used. At least it works in older versions, we use that a lot here. I don't know how 3DS Max would deal with it.